Only with openssh client I can't connect to a remote server, with any other ssh client it works
When I try to ssh to a remote server, I get no response from the server, and after about 10 seconds I get a disconnect message (port 22). The situation occurs only if I use openssh-client, any other client (putty, remmina, windows powershell) connects without problems. The server and the client have installed Debian 12 stable.
Considering that I don't have this problem on other servers, I didn't manage to find a solution. Thank you for any possible suggestion.
blu@blue:~/Desktop$ ssh -vvv blu@tuxblue.eu
OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3, OpenSSL 3.0.15 3 Sep 2024
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/blu/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/blu/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "tuxblue.eu" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup tuxblue.eu:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to tuxblue.eu [91.200.220.102] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/blu/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3
debug1: compat_banner: match: OpenSSH_9.2p1 Debian-2+deb12u3 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to tuxblue.eu:22 as 'blu'
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /home/blu/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: no algorithms matched; accept original
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
Connection reset by 91.200.220.102 port 22


Run with -vvv, check for errors.

debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent Connection reset by 91.200.220.102 port 22

Check this, looks like your situation: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65921478/connection-reset-by-1-port-22-windows-10-powershell-cmd-openssh And also the rest: https://www.google.com/search?q=openssh+%22Connection+reset+by%22

Is  that on Windows? Which build of openssh client are you using? The one from cygwin or from git-for-windows? Or the buggy fork by Microsoft?

@StéphaneChazelas it looks like it could be Debian(-ish) on WSL. If it was the Microsoft one I'd expect to see Windows/DOS style paths (with backslashes as directory separators)

No Windows here. I only specified that everything works perfectly except for openssh-client which is installed on Debian 12 stable.

Timeout is almost always, and RST usually, a network problem. If you can, get network captures at both endpoints, with wireshark if available else tcpdump, filtering port 22 to avoid clutter, and compare sent with received; also look for retransmissions and sequence gaps (which wireshark will conveniently flag for you).
